# How can I set up a private internal DNS server?

Tags: windows, internal-dns

We have a windows server box in our office and then a number of desktop pc's running xp, and windows 7.

All of our project'd databases sit on our server and each person uses SourceSafe for controlling versioning of the files.

The dns entry to the server is something like ourcompany.com

I would like to set up each machine in the office so that everyone can access another's pc by going to http://justin.ourcompany.com as an example which then hits Justin's machine which should be set to his localhost's project.

We had this working at one stage and we're not sure why it not working any more.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you install a DNS Server locally to the same domain that you have in internet, None of user will resolve it, because the new installed is the "propietary" of that domain. Put the stations in A.D. Domain.

Comment: http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/dns2003/ should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as the comment states above by putting them in AD or you can set your DNS on all your clients to your server and setup a records to the effect of Justin.example.com 192.168.1.X and Bob.example.com to 192.168.1.xx. You need to make sure that your DNS and your clients all have static IPs or you will have issues when a PC switches addresses.